# How to complete columns in a data frame from left to right

Tags: r

I have a data frame for which I would like to *complete* the columns from left to right by using the lasted non NA value and adding `(foo)` suffix after it. For example, this data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("one", "one", "three"),
  y = c("two", "four", NA),
  z = c("three", NA, NA)
)

df
#>       x    y     z
#> 1   one  two three
#> 2   one four  <NA>
#> 3 three <NA>  <NA>
```

would produce:

```r
data.frame(
  x = c("one", "one", "three"),
  y = c("two", "four", "three (foo)"),
  z = c("three", "four (foo)", "three (foo)")
)
#>       x           y           z
#> 1   one         two       three
#> 2   one        four  four (foo)
#> 3 three three (foo) three (foo)
```

Is there an elegant way to do it? It can be base R, tidyverse or data.table solution.
<sup>Created on 2019-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There's a better way to do this, but : for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { df[i,which(is.na(df[i,]))] = df[i,which(is.na(df[i,]))-1] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(new = row_number()) %>% 
 gather(var, val, - new) %>% 
 group_by(new) %>% 
 mutate(flag = as.integer(is.na(val))) %>% 
 fill(val) %>% 
 mutate(val = replace(val, flag == 1, paste(val[flag == 1], '(foo)')))  %>% 
 select(-flag) %>% 
 spread(var, val)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
> # Groups:   new [3]
>     new x     y           z          
>   <int> <chr> <chr>       <chr>      
> 1     1 one   two         three      
> 2     2 one   four        four (foo) 
> 3     3 three three (foo) three (foo)
> ```

Comment: Just a small detail, but can use `rowid_to_column()` instead :)

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk. I was not aware of that function. What package is it from?

Comment: From `tibble`, so it's quite handy for `tidyverse` solutions.

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Ok...Nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `base` package and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c("one", "one", "three"),
  y = c("two", "four", NA),
  z = c("three", NA, NA)
)

nalast = function(x){
  l1 = x
  nas = is.na(l1)
  l1[nas] = paste0(x[tail(which(!nas),n=1)]," (foo)")
  return(l1)
}

df2 = apply(X = df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = nalast)

df2
```

Wich gives

```
> df2
     x       y            z            
[1,] "one"   "two"        "three"      
[2,] "one"   "four"       "three (foo)"
[3,] "three" "four (foo)" "three (foo)"
>
```